# How should I handle revoking permission in application runtime?

Tags: android

I am considering following problem: 
User uses the app, puts it in background, go to device settings and revokes permission.

Application process is being killed and Activity stack is being recreated, but I have a bunch o Singletons that are dead now and in normall application startup they are initialized on splash screen.

Now I am in the point where the best solution would be to kill current process a, restart whole application and ask for permission again as I cannot use the app without that certain permission and the question is: How should I accomplish that ?

The only way that I imagine and would work for me would be checking if I have permission(and return + restart app) in onCreate of EVERY activity in my application. This seems to be an ugly solution in my opinion so I want to ask you how do you handle such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Considering the fact that application I need to maintain has a lot of wrong written code, singletons that needs to perform requests in order to initialize and so on. Solution I ended up with is like following:**

1 - I created my own abstract onCreate in "BaseActivity" called onCreateSafely

2 - I made onCreate in "BaseActivity" final so no one can override it(This is done to force developer to use onCreateSafely)

3 - In onCreate of "BaseActivity" I call onCreateSafely only if my permissions are granted AND my singletons feels good. Otherwise if this is not SplashScreen activity(which initializes them) I call finishAffinity and start SplashScreen activity.

4 - I moved onCreate's code in child activities to onCreateSafely

## #thanksgoogle

(it would be much easier if I could use some flag to change app behaviour (on "full restart") after revoking permission)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume on Android that you will always go through your splash screen.  If a user was to background you then bring you back from recents you could be killed between the two events and restarted in the inner activity.  You need to write code to detect that and handle it-  either by recreating your singletons in the onCreate of each activity, or by checking for the condition and redirecting to the splash screen for them to be recreated if that takes too long to do locally.

Answer (score 0):

This is why singletons on Android should usually be avoided. And if not, initialized in the Application override.
But, to solve your problem in a slightly less ugly way, you can use

```
getApplicaton().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(yourCustomClass);
```

Where `yourCustomClass` is responsible for checking the permission state and restarting your app.

Comment: I agree but we all live in the world of legacy code :( Unfortunately to initialize some singletons a configuration file needs to be downloaded from server so I cannot do this in Application.
I'm afraid that this is not acceptable solution as Activity lifecycle callback from this listener happens after Activity's coresponding method is being called(which might already cause nullpointers).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a base activity class which does this, then make all other activities extend it. The check functionality would be in `onResume`, because switching between apps does not call `onCreate`. And depending on how vital the permission is you can take actions, like exiting the app for example.

Comment: I'm afraid that this has no chance to work, crashes can happen on every activity's onCreate method. Even if restarting the app would be in Base activity's onCreate it would not prevent from finishing "child" activity's onCreate(which might cause the crash)